# Why I can't get the value of counter at output? It is showing like "The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times."

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here my output isn't showing the value of counter. Here I put my full `javascript` code. Also value of counter isn't increasing!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
    <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
    <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var example1 = new Vue({
                       el: '#example-1',
                       data: {
                       counter: 0
                       }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the `data` value.

```
<div id="example-1">
    <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
    <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var example1 = new Vue({
    el: '#example-1',
    data: data: function () {
    return { // need to return things
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  })
  </script>
```

Check this [out](https://codepen.io/yuanyu/pen/JOvEEJ) here.

Answer (score 1):

Data Must Be a [Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

```js
data: () => ({
    counter: 0
})
```

Comment: data can be a object also. in vue2\

Comment: I agree. In the root Vue instance, that is, built through `new Vue ({...})`, you can just use `data: {...}` without any problem. The problem is that you have reusable components that are defined via `Vue.component (...)`. In these cases, you need to either use data () {return {...};}` or `data: function () {return {...};}`.

Comment: The reason for this is to ensure that for every single instance of a reusable child component, there is a unique object that contains all the data to be processed. If in a child component you use `data: {...}` instead, then that same data object will be shared between the child components, which can cause some nasty errors.